# Startserver does not send data back to POpen.communicate

Tags: python

I got this script and it should start the simple server from my script:

```
import subprocess

cmd_line = "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out = p.communicate()[0]
print out
```

But I always get this error:

```
CTraceback (most recent call last):  File "startserver.py", line 5, in <module>
    out = p.communicate()[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 790, in communicate
    stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: How exactly do you start it?

Comment: In software development, it's far more often that we simply don't understand what we're doing than it is something "doesn't work." That is the case here, and it should be any programmer's default assumption until they can prove otherwise. I've edited the title to reflect the perceived problem instead of saying that "it doesn't work."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interrupting the program, the command starts a server so there is going to be no output using [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) as the data is buffered and communicate will wait until the process is finished, you only see the output `KeyboardInterrupt` when you stop the code running.

If you start the server and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` you will see it is running.

If you want to see the startup message and the output in real time use `iter` with `stdout.readline` and remove communicate:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '8000'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,""):
    print(line)
```

Which unless you catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` will still output one when you manually stop the code.

Comment: Sorry does not work. I used you code and I go this error : File "startserver.py", line 4, in <module>
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,"",universal_newlines=True):
TypeError: iter() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: sorry, had it in the wrong place. It should be fine now

Comment: if I run it without : "for line in iter". It runs without complaining but does nothing. If I go to 127.0.0.1:8000. I get webpage not available.

Comment: @user413734, the code works as posted, have you run the code after I edited?